# Can't invite internal tester for test flight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I just decided to release a new minor update through test flight.

Previous test flight version was 1.7.0.x and new one is 1.7.1.x.

When I tried to enable the test flight for new version. `iTunesConnect` said that "To start testing, invite at lease tester".

[image]

So, I clicked that link above, it jumped to `Internal Test` section. However, I could see already enabled testers.

To ensure the enablement state, I disabled all testers and enabled it again. The invitation emails were sent to testers. However the version of the invitation email was 1.7.0 not 1.7.1

Am I missing something? or is this temporary problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a temporary problem on Apple's end.

I'm also having problems.

TestFlight is experiencing problems according to: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: Thanks, the Apple's monitor is always late!